# Passing information from server to client using RTSP

Tags: rtsp

I using RTSP for transmitting video from server to client.
At some points during the transmission I need the server to "send" metadata to the client (some information that something was changed).
I need the sessions to be fully "standard" (VLC should be able to display the video).

I thought of sending DESCRIBE to the server at some interval from the client and using the SDP data to contain the relevant information.

Is it a "standard" approach? shouldn't the DESCRIBE be used for initialization purposes only?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the RTSP standard the DESCRIBE method simply describes the URL in the request and should only be used for that purpose. Try using GET_PARAMETER method or use extensibility features of [RTSP](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2326.txt).

Answer (score 0):

RTSP Draft 2.0 has support for PLAY_NOTIFY although I am not 100% sure that is what you need, you may just need to be able to have a server which is capable of sending an `Announce` from the Client to Server when the media changes... or that may be encompassed by just using dynamic as the payload types and specifying an additional payload type in the SDP...

My media server implementation should handle this easily and contains a RtspClient which may help also!

http://net7mma.codeplex.com